# Jumping to a point in a navigation stack

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

Just after a bit of advice really and a push in the right direction.

I have a modal view with a navigation controller containing 3 levels (views):

1. My Active Jobs (pulls a list of the users active jobs from the server and displays as a table, select a job and view 2 is passed the jobID and displayed).
2. Job Details (pulls the job details and a list of its updates based on the jobID from the server, select an update and view 3 is passed the updateID and displayed).
3. Update Details (pulls the details of the update based on the updateID from the server and any photos attached to that update, select a photo and it displays full screen.

So I have a seperate modal view in a different part of the app which displays the latest updates to the jobs. This includes new jobs assigned to the user and new updates for active jobs.

What I would like to do is link directly to the relevant view in the navigation controller when an item is selected in the latest updates modal window.

So my thoughts are to call the the Active jobs modal view when a latest update is selected and pass the relevant ID(s), initialise the combination of views needed in the stack pass the ID(s) to the views then initialise the navigation controller with the setViewControllers:animated: method.

Is this the best way to do it, or is there a better way?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason to duplicate the functionality of creating the views for the view controller. One thing you could do is have a "cache" for each element (jobId and updateId ). If you want to push multiple viewControllers at once you would fill the cache with the desired values. Then when you push a viewController onto the navigationController, the new controller would check the cache and if there is something cached you would simply push the next view controller directly. This would all happen quickly and should be unnoticeable to the user.

By doing it this way, you are using the same code regardless of if you know the next id or not. You are either using the user selected id, or the one already predefined by the other selection.